# SSL issue using browsermob proxy 2.1.0

Tags: java, ssl, browsermob-proxy

Geting following exception on browsermob proxy.

We have import Cyber villain cert to our browser(Firefox). Also website cert have been imported to java cacert. When we try to browser website on https, page is broken and we see following excepion on proxy server

Please find stack trace here http://pastebin.com/AstVhNGY

Just 2 line on stack trace

> ERROR 2015-11-28T14:02:34,418
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection]
>   (LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-3) (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id:
>   0x1db9cf60, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53483 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081]: Caught
>   an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
>   io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
>           at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:358)
>   ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-3.jar:?]

Comment: Hi Kadir,

There is no such code. We are trying manually. 
We have configured browser mob as proxy server and set browser proxy to browser mob port
We are able to access http and other protocols. But on trying https websites, we were getting above exception which is cert issue.
So we added Cybervillain as trusted certificate to the browser, but even we get above exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is a user reported similar issue in browserMob proxy community https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/221. Looks like it has been fixed.